# How to write a script which uses gdb?

Tags: automation, gdb

I have a binary file which I compiled with "-g -O2" g++ options. I also have few core dump files created after my binary crashed. What I'm doing manually is to call `gdb` with the binary and a core dump file as parameters, then use "info threads" to know how many threads I have and then for every thread I do "thread n" where n is the thread number and then "bt" to see the back trace. Is it possible to automate this procedure using a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW it is simpler to use this to see a backtrace in all threads:

```
thread apply all bt
```

You may also like

```
thread apply all bt full
```

which shows all the local variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess that was any easy question. Since my binary has a constant amount of threads I wrote a script named gdb.cmd with the following content

```
set pagination off
info threads
thread 1
bt
thread 2
bt
...
thread 11
bt
q
```

And then using bash for loop

```
for f in `ls core.*` ; do gdb <binary name> $f -x gdb.cmd > /tmp/$f ; done
```